# evaluate the double integral with respect to D

Tags: integration

Evaluate the following double integral $∫∫_D(x^2 + xy − y^2)dx dy$ where $D$ is the region in the first quadrant bounded by $x = 0, y = x^2$ and $y = 1$.

I can confidently evaluate double integrals but I am unsure of the wording in regards to $D$ and what this does to the boundaries.

Similarly for the second part evaluate $∫∫_D(1 + xy)dx dy$ where $D$  is the region satisfied $y ≥ 0$ and $1 ≤ x^2 + y^2 ≤ 2$, I do not understand what this does to the boundaries. Thanks.

Comment: Hint: Just try to draw this region $D$ and look at what boundaries you get for $x$ and $y$. The boundary for $x$ might depend on $y$ and vice versa.

Comment: 80% of these problems is about evaluating the regions and finding the limits of integration.  In the first problem D is pretty straight forward bounded on two sides by straight lines and on the 3rd by a section of a parabola.  In the second problem you have an annulus, and I suggest you consider converting to polar coordinates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For for the first problem, here's the drawing

[image]

There are two regions enclosed by the curves, but because we need the one in the first quadrant we take the one on the right.

Imagine shooting a laser straight parallel to the the $y$ direction from the bottom. The laser would start off hitting the region at the curve $y=x^2$ then it would it would hit the curve $y=1$.

That tells us we can let  $y \in [x^2,1]$. But we have to account for which values of $x$ are allowed. Once we have accounted for moving up/down in the region for a value of $x$, we have to account for moving left/right. Clearly we may vary $x \in [0,1]$.

So the integration bounds for the first problem are,

$$\int_{0}^{1} \int_{x^2}^{1} dy dx$$

For the second problem, here's the picture

[image]

It's a donut shape but be careful we need $y \geq 0$. So ignore the third and fourth quadrant and only pay attention to the quadrants on top of them.

By the circular nature of the problem, polar coordinates are advised.

For the donut shape with $y \geq 0$ the distance from the origin for any choice of $\theta$ varies from $1$ to $\sqrt{2}$. We may vary the counterclockwise angle from $\theta \in [0,\pi]$. Because we are interested in the part of the donut that is in the first and second quadrants.  So, not forgetting the jacobian $r$, the integration bounds are,

$$\int_{0}^{\pi} \int_{1}^{\sqrt{2}}  r  dr d\theta$$